# Нахождение уединённых окружностей, предложите оптимальный вариант решения

Tags: массивы, файлы, структуры, c++, visual-c++

Задание:
Дан файл, содержащий сведения об окружностях (радиус и координаты центра). Переписать в файл G все уединенные окружности, т.е. окружности, не имеющие пересечений с другими окружностями. Реализовать на двоичных файлах с помощью структур данных (struct). 
В общем то запись в файл и чтение из него затруднений не вызвали
Но я всё думаю как рациональнее проверить окружности на пересечение в массиве

FILE *f,*g;

```
struct Round
{
double X,Y;
double radius;
};

Round UED(Round x1,Round x2,Round y1,Round y2,Round r1,Round r2)
{
Round len.radius= sqrt((x2.X - x1.X) * (x2.X - x1.X) + (y2.Y - y1.Y) * (y2.Y -y1.Y));
    if (len.radius > r1.radius + r2.radius)
      return len;
}

void main()
{
system("color F0");
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
int n;
printf("Введите количество окружностей: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
if(n<2)
printf("Это не о чём не говорит\n");
Round O;
f=fopen("data.okr","wb");
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  printf("Введите координаты центра окружности: ");
  scanf("%lg%lg",&O.X,&O.Y);
  printf("Введите длину радиуса окружности: ");
  scanf("%lg",&O.radius);
  fwrite(&O,sizeof(Round),1,f);
}
 printf("Данные внесены\n");
fclose(f);
Round *okr;
okr=new Round[n];
int i=0;
fopen("data.okr","rb");
while(true)
{

    fread(&okr[i],sizeof(Round),1,f);
     if(feof(f))
         break;
     printf("\nкоординаты центра окружности: %lg\t %lg ",okr[i].X,okr[i].Y);
     printf(" \nдлина радиуса окружности: %lg",okr[i].radius);
     i++;
}
fclose(f);
_getch();
}
```

По требованию препода данные в функцию

Round UED(Round x1,Round x2,Round y1,Round y2,Round r1,Round r2)
    {
    Round len.radius= sqrt((x2.X - x1.X) * (x2.X - x1.X) + (y2.Y - y1.Y) * (y2.Y -y1.Y));
        if (len.radius > r1.radius + r2.radius)
          return len;
    }
 Должны подаваться через массив, не уж то 3 цикла заводить???

Comment: Ну, вероятно, не 3, а два.

     for(int i=0; i < n-1; i++) 
       for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
         ..

А почему у Вас x1, x2, y1, y2, r1, r2, len -- окружности? Чисел тут недостаточно?

     Round UED(Round x1,Round x2,Round y1,Round y2,Round r1,Round r2) { 
       Round len.radius= sqrt((x2.X - x1.X) * (x2.X - x1.X) + (y2.Y - y1.Y) * (y2.Y -y1.Y));
       if (len.radius > r1.radius + r2.radius) return len;
     }

Comment: @alexlz: Числами несемантично. Другое дело, что

   Round x1,Round x2,Round y1,Round y2

— бессмыслица: в структуре `Round` и так есть и радиус, и обе координаты центра.

Comment: @VladD это же круто -- для каждого атрибута своя окружность. И вызов этой функции становится интересней, особливо если преподаватель ещё и к алиасингу придираться надумает.

Comment: @alexlz: Угу. Может, это окружности высшего порядка, а мы-то не догоняем?

Comment: @VladD всё могет быть. Только вот у парня сессия на носу (или уже началась), зачёт надо, икру мечет -- не знает, как выкрутиться, ошибок делает ещё больше, чем обычно, а тут над ним ещё и прикалываются...

Comment: @alexlz: Не стоит помогать двоечникам — они станут нашими начальниками (ц)

Comment: @factura, вроде бы формулы для определения пересечения [несколько сложнее](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/circles_intersection)

Comment: @avp: По идее, формула правильная: это просто проверка неравенства треугольника для точек O1, O2 и точки пересечения. Но вот имплементация, конечно, оставляет желать лучшего.

Comment: @avp, @VladD глубокие изыскания. Расстояние между центрами больше суммы радиусов. @avp ему же точки пересечения не нужны. И даже если их нет, но один внутри другого -- тоже "неодинокая" окружность.

Comment: Извиняюсь, что отвечу тут на комментарий внизу, но там закончилось место. @avp, когда код маленький, то все нормально, но когда он большой и в теле начинают встречаться много несвязных сокращений, то это усложняет понимание и каждый раз смотреть в заголовок не есть хорошо. Я конечно не призываю поступать как рубисты, но и пренебрегать названиями тоже не советую. В остальном предлагаю оставить этот оффтоп, поскольку формат хешкода как я понимаю не позволяет вести дискуссии.

Comment: @Alexey123, согласен, тем более, что о *маленьком коде* Вы как раз сказали.

Answer (score 2):

Наверное, стоит помочь парню, все-таки старается ;) Только в логике надо порядок навести.

1. Функции. Лучше, если их будет 2. Первая - ваша, для проверки пересечения, только учтите замечания насчет типов: она должна получать 2 окружности (Round) и возвращать bool (или int). Вторая - с двумя циклами для сравнения каждой с каждой (i,j=[0,n-1], i!=j). Вот она и будет получать массив, но только один - исходный, и записывать в файл одинокие окружности.
2. При определении пересечения можно не извлекать корень, а возвести сумму радиусов в квадрат. И, кстати, что возвращает UED, если условие не выполняется? Такую функцию, чтобы не было тавтологии и при условии, что с параметрами разберетесь, лучше реализовать так (и не надо даже if!):

   ```
   return (x2.X - x1.X) * (x2.X - x1.X) + (y2.Y - y1.Y) * (y2.Y -y1.Y) > (r1.radius + r2.radius) * (r1.radius + r2.radius);
   ```
3. Если при чтении из двоичного файла вам заранее известно количество элементов, то читать можно проще, все сразу. А потом напечатайте массив в отдельном цикле.

   ```
   fread(okr,sizeof(Round),n,f); // UPD
   ```
4. Вывод массива лучше тоже реализовать как функцию, порадуйте препода ;)

Comment: @paulgri: К вашему пункту 2: чё-то вы не то советуете. В каком параметре приходит первая окружность? Вторая? Почему `x2.X`, но `y2.Y`?

Comment: @VladD, видимо он советует исходя из первоначальной функции ТС, а не своего ответа в пункте 1. А в общем случае, не надо лениться и сокращать названия(за x2 x1 y2 y1 надо наказывать перезачетом).

Comment: Должно быть так: в функцию передаются два параметра, это окружности: Round round_1 и Round round_2. Расстояние между центрами должно быть больше суммы радиусов для не пересекающихся окружностей: sqrt((round_1.x - round_2.x)*(round_1.x - round_2.x) + (round_1.y - round_2.y)*(round_1.y - round_2.y)) > round_1.radius + round_2.radius. Можно без корня, возведя обе стороны уравнения в квадрат, хотя я бы не стал жертвовать пониманием на производительность в институтских задачах.

Comment: @Alexey123, спасибо! @VladD, конечно, это еще ерунда, а когда ТС по п.1 наведет порядок, все будет ок :) Суть п.2 в том, что умножать дешевле, чем извлекать корень, а если одно число больше другого, то и их квадраты будут находиться в том же отношении.

Comment: @paulgri: Вы, конечно, правы, но это уже оптимизация, а здесь ТСу сначала бы базовое понимание того, что он делает.

Comment: @VladD, согласен, увлекся на тему квадратов. Но что касается неполной конструкции и тавтологии у ТС - это как раз к базовому пониманию относится. Код должен быть корректен и лаконичен.

Comment: @Alexey123 А чем `round_1` и `round_2` лучше `x1` и `x2`?

Comment: @alexlz: Тем, что `x1` говорит программисту, что это лишь `x`-координата первой окружности. То есть имя противоречит семантике и отвлекает читателя. (Да, я знаю про α-conversion, но nomen est omen.)

Comment: Как уже сказали в семантике. Когда видишь функцию Round UED(Round x1,Round x2,Round y1,Round y2,Round r1,Round r2), то первая мысль - почему UED и зачем в этом методе целых шесть окружностей? Соответственно я трачу время на выяснение этих деталей, хотя простая правка Round collisionRounds(Round xCoordFirstRound,Round xCoordSecondRound, Round yCoordFirstRound, ... и т.д хотя бы позволила легче разобраться(видимо у автора какие-то причины передавать координаты в структурах). А что если бы эта функция была сложнее и в ней надо было бы разобраться без пояснений?

Comment: В данном случае хотя Round collisionRounds(Round x1, Round x2) не так страшно путают из-за краткости, но все же лучше сохранить семантику Round collisionRounds(Round round_1, Round round_2) + получается автодокументирование именами.

Comment: @Alexey123, а Вам не кажется, что `Round round_1` это, так сказать *масло масленое*?

Вполне достаточно


     bool  collisionRounds(Round r1, Round r2); // is_intersecting_circles(...) ?

поскольку речь идет просто о любых окружностях.

Comment: @avp: Тогда уж

    bool intersects(Circle _1, Circle _2);

Тут уж точно нет лишнего.

Comment: @VladD, [начинать с underscore такие имена не рекомендуют](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)